# Convert tabular data to Nested dictionary representing a tree

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to convert data from a table to a nested dictionary using Python 2.7.

This is a sample of the data -

```
P  C  GC  GGC  
--------------
P1 C1 GC1 GGC1
P1 C1 GC1 GGC2
P1 C1 GC2 GGC3
P1 C1 GC2 GGC4
P1 C1 GC2 GGC5
P1 C2 GC3 GGC6
P1 C2 GC3 GGC7
P1 C2 GC4 GGC8
P1 C2 GC4 GGC9
P2 C3 GC5 GGC10
P2 C3 GC5 GGC11
P2 C3 GC5 GGC12
```

Here the columns in the row represent a parent, a child, a grand child, a great GC. Here this implies that the hierarchy is 4 levels deep. (I have a case where there could be 5 or 6 levels deep but I do not need the solution to dynamically adjust to the levels. A solution hard coded to 4 levels is fine).

I need to convert this data into a nested dictionary representing a tree. (This later goes into a UI treeview type of element).

The expected output is -

```
[
  {
    text: "P1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "C1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "GC1",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "GGC1"
              },
              {
                text: "GGC2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            text: "GC2",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "GGC3"
              },
              {
                text: "GGC4"
              },
              {
                text: "GGC5"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "C2",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "GC3",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "GGC6"
              },
              {
                text: "GGC7"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            text: "GC4",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "GGC8"
              },
              {
                text: "GGC9"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "P2",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "C3",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "GC5",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "GGC10"
              },
              {
                text: "GGC12"
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here every column in a row gets translated to its level within the hierarchy. The parents essentially are at the top of hierarchy.

What is the best way to solve this? (A solution using pandas < 0.15.1 is fine too).

PS - Python newbie here.

Comment: This is not nested dictionary!

Comment: @WoodChopper - If you have some suggestions, please let me know. I can  try editing the subject if SO allows me to.

Comment: Do you want output in that in that structure?

Comment: Yes. I need to try to get it into an list of nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the df and print to get similar structure,

I have used pandas dataframe for table but its not necessary. you could use simple list.

```
df
Out[36]: 
        km  price   1b  1c   1d
0   240000   3650  hey  yo  OMG
1   139800   3800  hey  yo  OMG
2   150500   4400  hey  yo  OMG
3   185530   4450  hey  yo  OMG
4   176000   5250  hey  yo  OMG
5   114800   5350  hey  yo  OMG
6   166800   5800  hey  yo  OMG
7    89000   5990  hey  yo  OMG
8   144500   5999  hey  yo  OMG
9    84000   6200  hey  yo  OMG
10   82029   6390  hey  yo  OMG



 for x in df.iterrows():
    print '{text: "%s",nodes: [{text: "%s",nodes: [{text: "%s",nodes: [{text: "%s" },{text: "%s"}]},]}]},' % (x[1][0], x[1][1],x[1][2], x[1][3], x[1][4])

{text: "240000",nodes: [{text: "3650",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "139800",nodes: [{text: "3800",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "150500",nodes: [{text: "4400",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "185530",nodes: [{text: "4450",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "176000",nodes: [{text: "5250",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "114800",nodes: [{text: "5350",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "166800",nodes: [{text: "5800",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "89000",nodes: [{text: "5990",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "144500",nodes: [{text: "5999",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "84000",nodes: [{text: "6200",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
{text: "82029",nodes: [{text: "6390",nodes: [{text: "hey",nodes: [{text: "yo" },{text: "OMG"}]},]}]},
```

Comment: @Afp I this answered your question please don't forget to accept the answer.